# decltype for overloaded member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have this code:

```
struct Foo 
{
    int print(int a, double b);
    int print(int a);
    void print();
    void print(int a, int b, int c);

    void other();
};
```

I can call

```
decltype(&Foo::other)
```

but calling

```
decltype(&Foo::print)
```

end with error, which is clear to me.

But how can I specify more "closely" which of the four `print` methods, I want to resolve to `decltype`?

I want to further use this in

```
template <class MT>
struct method_info;

template <class T, class Res, class... Args>
struct method_info<Res(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    typedef std::tuple<Args&&...> args_tuple;
    typedef T ClassType;
    typedef Res RetVal; 
};



template <class MethodType>
void func() {
   typedef method_info<MethodType> MethodInfo;
   .....
}

func<decltype(&Foo::other)>();
....
```

Comment: What do you mean by *more "closely"*?  If the function is overloaded you have to specify exactly which version you want when using it.

Comment: Is this the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) you're looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More "closely", as far as I understand, means you want to specify the function arguments of `print`. That is, for example, you select `int, int`, then get back the result-type of `Foo{}.print(int{},int{})`, and thereafter construct a function pointer from all the available information.

Here is an alias template which does that for you in a general way:

```
template<typename ... Args>
using ptr_to_print_type = decltype(std::declval<Foo>().print(std::declval<Args>() ...)) (Foo::*)(Args ...);
```

You could also use `std::result_of` instead of the `std::declval` stuff, but I like the latter more.

You can use the above as

```
func<ptr_to_print_type<int,int> >();
```

---

EDIT: as asked for by @JavaLover, which btw seems like an unsuitable name for such horrible C++ shit :-), here is the same as above using `std::result_of` (<s>untested</s> now tested and wrong):

```
//------ does not compile for overloaded functions --------
template<typename ... Args>
using ptr_to_print_type = std::result_of_t<decltype(&Foo::print)(Foo, Args ...)> (Foo::*)(Args ...)
//------ does not compile for overloaded functions --------
```

You could further abstract away the `Foo` but not the `print` (unless you're using macros).

Comment: This is the best post I found after searching for several hours. Thank. May you also provide the `std::result_of` example, please?

Comment: @javaLover: thanks. I made an edit.

Comment: Thank a lot.  In the new `std::result_of` version, the compiler can't resolve the overloaded function, though.   Here are [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c75739a460787e0e) and [backup](http://ideone.com/3vPkzd).   It is confused at  `(&Foo::print)`.   If I replace the `version2` line with the old `version1` line, it will work.

Comment: @javaLover: mhh, you're right, can't bring it to work either ... seems like a limitation of the second approach (it probably could be done along the lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17875252/2412846), but it's tedious). This is why I said I like the `decltype / declval` stuff more -- it's rather clear there what is going on. Just read `decltype` as "give me the type" and `declval` as "give me the object (--but without issues caused by a missing default constructor, etc.)".

Comment: This will however fail if the arguments get implicitly converted to the method's proper types: the resulting method pointer will have a different signature than then real one.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the exact syntax but, in case of method name overloading, you should cast the pointer; something like

```
static_cast<void(Foo::*)(int, int, int)>(&Foo::print);
```

In you're interested only in type, should be the template value of the cast

```
void(Foo::*)(int, int, int)
```