# Is it possible to deduce the signature of the resolved method/function overload even in case of implicit parameters conversions?

Tags: c++11, templates, metaprogramming, decltype, method-signature

Say we have

```c++
struct Test {
    void foo(int *);
    void foo(float);
} test;
```

Given the the following method call:

```c++
test.foo(1);
```

The compiler will resolve it by invoking `Test::foo(float)`, doing the implicit conversion from `int` to `float`.

Is it possible to somehow get the signature of the thus resolved method overload as a pointer type, i.e. `void (Test::*)(float)`?

The closest thing to a positive answer I could get is [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40135913/566849), however that approach will fail in case of an implicit conversion of one or more parameters.