# Traits of overloaded functions

Tags: c++, type-traits

I am trying to get the return type of a function with const/non const overloads.

```
struct TestClass {
    const int* getPtr() const { return ptr; }
    int* getPtr() { return ptr; }
private:
    int* ptr;
};

using return_ptr_type = typename std::invoke_result<decltype(&TestClass::getPtr), TestClass>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<return_ptr_type, int*>::value);
```

Compiler complains that it cannot resolve address of overloaded function. I understand why this happens, but not how to fix it.

Note: I see other questions on stack overflow on how to resolve between overloads, but they deal with overloads with different function arguments, not const overloads.

Comment: What about this: https://onlinegdb.com/hkZZQqF0H

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135561/decltype-for-overloaded-member-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `decltype(&TestClass::getPtr)` overload resolution won't happen; there're even no context for compilers to choose one.

You can get the return type by calling `getPtr()` on const or non-const object, to make overload resolution taking effect. e.g.

```
using return_ptr_type1 = decltype(std::declval<TestClass>().getPtr());
static_assert(std::is_same<return_ptr_type1, int*>::value);

using return_ptr_type2 = decltype(std::declval<const TestClass>().getPtr());
static_assert(std::is_same<return_ptr_type2, const int*>::value);
```

Comment: Also `&` might be smart if you don't want rvalue overloads.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Sway: see [ref-qualified_member_functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions)